# How to get single output/result from two rows using one query

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get value from database , but I'm still unlucky to combine two queries to get one result.

Scenario:

1. I want to get the MIN of timein using employee_id and date
2. I want to get the MAX of timeout using employee_id and date

Is this possible ?

**QUERY I USED**

```
 $data = DB::table('tbl_dtr_logs')
         ->join('tbl_employees_pi','tbl_employees_pi.id','=','tbl_dtr_logs.employee_id')
         ->select('tbl_employees_pi.*')

         ->addSelect(DB::raw('MIN(log_timestamp) as timein'))
         ->where(['log_date'=>$date,'log_type'=>'timein'])

         ->addSelect(DB::raw('MAX(log_timestamp) as timeout FROM tbl_dtr_logs '))
         ->groupBy('log_date','employee_id')->get();
```

**TABLE**

```
| id |  type  | log_timestamp       | employee_id | log_date |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | timein | 2019-08-16 06:54:36 |  1          | 2019-08-16
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | timeout| 2019-08-16 09:00:00 |  1          | 2019-08-16
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 3  | timein | 2019-08-16 07:00:36 |  2          | 2019-08-16
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 4  | timeout| 2019-08-16 09:30:00 |  2          | 2019-08-16
```

**RESULT**

```
Output should like this :

0 => {id: 1,
timein : 2019-08-16 06:54:36 ,
timeout: 2019-08-16 09:00:00 ,
employee_id:  1,
log_date: 2019-08-16},

1 => {id: 1,
timein : 2019-08-16 07:00:36 ,
timeout: 2019-08-16 09:30:00 ,
employee_id:  1,
log_date: 2019-08-16},
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by a `date` instead of a `datetime`. You can convert a `mysql` `datetime` to date with `date()`. So change your group by to this, utilizing `db::raw` function.

```
->groupBy(DB::raw('date(log_date) as other_date'), 'employee_id')
```

Comment: Thank you  for your response sir! but unfortunately isn't work in my case, even I have changed already what you said sir.

Comment: i looked through the question several time, you want to group the timein with timeout, but i do not think there is data relation between those

Comment: Yes sir between two different rows that i just based the log_date and employee id to get the time in time out

Comment: But what happens when you apply the changes?

Comment: It results to an error which is about Cardinal Rule.

Comment: If you change the as statement to 'as other_date' does it help

Comment: Thanks for some advice sir !! :) , Now I solved by using SQL LEFT JOIN query in MYSQL as my testing if possible then I will translate  into Laravel query.